# Is the "rss" tag necessary?

Tags: discussion, tags

I see there are [feeds](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feeds) and [rss](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rss), but I don't see any [atom](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/atom).

If there aren't tags for other types of feed, is [rss](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rss) needed?

Comment: Does "feeds" refer to everything that is a news feed (RSS, atom, etc) or the module called "Feeds" ?

Comment: @HedgeMage Looking at the questions tagged "feeds," I get it is referring to news feeds, not the module. As the module handles news feeds, I think that there isn't much distinction between the two cases, in the same way "views" could refer to the module, or the output of that module.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A lot of people, especially developers, tend to refer to feeds as "rss", regardless of flavor.

I recommend [rss](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rss) be made a synonym for [feeds](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feeds) and then merged. Can anyone think of a good reason why either one of these tags would be needed for any other purpose?

Comment: I think merging would be a good idea. Waiting for more feedback before doing anything yet.

Comment: I disagree of the merging of these 2 tags, but maybe convert the "feeds" in "feeds-module" to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: @tostinni What would you use for a question about feeds?

Comment: @kiamlaluno, I think rss is very generic and commonly used to mean feed, who cares nowadays of the differences between rss and atom ? All readers support both, and in fact I've heard way more "rss reader" instead of "feed reader".

Comment: @tostinni It's not very generic, as RSS is a feed format, but not all feeds use the RSS format.

Comment: @kiamlaluno, it's generic in the same sense that you say a MP3 player and not a digital music player, so yes it's not etymologically correct but it is commonly used and also I think it it's quite important to not confuse discussion about the feeds module.